# Can I connect two rechargable LI batteries of different specs in parallel?

Tags: batteries, parallel, discharge

More specifically, can I combine a high-discharge battery with a high-capacity battery if I want periodic high discharges combined with the higher capacity?

For example, if I wanted to pair a high-capacity [Panasonic NCR18650B](http://industrial.panasonic.com/lecs/www-data/pdf2/ACA4000/ACA4000CE417.pdf) with a high-discharge [Samsung INR18650-25R](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BwO0M-Quz5OhbHZwR3MyWG9KU28/edit?usp=docslist_api), where the capacities are 3350mah and 2560 mah, and the continuous discharge rates are 6A and 20A, could I hope for say 25A continuous discharge rates over a 10-15 seconds, with an total capacity of around 5400 mah? how can I calculate for other numbers as far as time/discharge rates for other combinations?

Comment: How do you make sure that only 6A are drawn from the NCR18650B? The INR will drop faster in voltage than the NCR and then more current will be drawn from the NCR and everything will explode (not literally hopefully).

Comment: @Arsenal well because it has a higher internal resistance, I figured less would be drawn for it - and after the spike, I expect the NCR to recharge the INR - similar to what would happen when putting two of the same battery in parallel and them ending up with different capacities due to manufacturing processes

Comment: This does not sound very promising. The only way you can avoid having high current flowing from one cell to the other is if they are constantly maintained at the same Voltage. The only way you can respect a current limit on the Panasonic cell is to force the Samsung to supply the brief high currents which will cause the two cells to have different voltages. Seems like a predicament. I am not going to say it is impossible, but for me, there would have to be very compelling reasons to overcome the difficulties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is generally a bad idea to parallel Li batteries unless you are capable of measuring (and matching) their internal resistance. [Experiments have shown](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/192208/54580) that even a 20% imbalance in said resistance can (approximately) halve their lifetime, in terms of cycles.

For Li batteries of different types, chances are that the imbalance in internal resistance will be huge on the milliohmic scale that matters here; the batteries in the test I mentioned were all of the same type and had resistance between 0.015 and 0.021 ohms. Still a mismatched pair lasted only half the cycles what well-matched paid did.

So I think this mostly rules out using different types directly in parallel. The currents circulating between the batteries you mention could in fact get dangerously high. What happens when one battery discharges? The Li batteries don't have nice linear curve near the end of their charge, but it drops sharply, which basically means that the other battery will see nearly a dead short.

[image]

So you can't safely parallel them directly; you'll need an electronic circuit to switch between them. I don't know off the top of my head a controller designed to work with different cells in the way you want. Maybe something exist though; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battery_balancing for the general idea. In general, these chips are designed for imbalances on the order of a few percent. What you ask for here is an imbalance of roughly 30% in mAh ratings.