# Heating pad circuit

Tags: batteries, current, usb

I am not confident with my design of the warmer circuit. Could anyone give me some advice on the circuit? [image: Rechargeable Warmer Circuit]

Comment: I am going to assume that those are lithium batteries - if so, you will want to make sure that they don't get over discharged - i.e. have something that will cut the current flow if their voltage goes below X (~2.5v?) - you would also probably want some sort of temperature sensor on the heating pads themselves physically (can't see if there is anything like that in the thermostat switch), and depending on what your heating a fan or some heat sink on the heating pads as well.

Comment: Hi user2813274, thanks for your prompt reply. But why do we need to ensure that the batteries don't over discharge?

Comment: Lithium batteries (which I assume you are using due to the USB charger module) will be unable to be recharged if they are discharged beyond a certain threshold (irreversible damage is done to the cells by the discharge) - and seeing as how a charger module wouldn't make much sense without rechargeable batteries..

Comment: Ah...I see, thank you very much. In fact these batteries were made by our materials lab. No wonder they have a few that are not working anymore. That explains it.

Comment: While it is good to avoid over-discharge, it is not entirely true that they cannot be recharged after an over-discharge. You can discharge a lithium battery to 0V at least once without losing a large amount of capacity. But the vendors do not recommend it. It could shorten the cycle life, and even help to introduce flaws which could cause catastrophic battery failure later.

Comment: Go talk to your materials lab and see what they recommend for charging cells in parallel?  What are the over and under voltage and over current limits?  Will you need to balance the cells or have individual over current limiting?

Comment: Thank you, mkeith and KalleMP. I have written an email to ask the materials lab. Waiting for their replies.

Answer (score 1):

Paralleling Li-ion batteries is not a good idea unless you know what's involved in that and have equipment to do factory-level measurements (mainly of the minute internal resistance). See [Charging Li-ion batteries in parallel](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/126673/charging-li-ion-batteries-in-parallel/192208#192208)  for more details.

Comment: @Icp: regarding over-discharge, you can buy "pouches" that have the  over-charge/over-discharge protection circuitry [built-in](https://learn.adafruit.com/li-ion-and-lipoly-batteries/protection-circuitry). The typical protection circuits use an IC like http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm3641.pdf and external FETs; newer ones have more integrated bits so need fewer extra parts. That won't solve your problem with much reduced battery life by haphazard paralleling though. You need to buy factory matched bundles for that (or have the ability to do in-house matching).

Comment: Hi Fluff, noted and I appreciate your inputs and reminders. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks, Fizz. I have just completed the prototype and the client likes it very much. Yes eventually I will be building a more complicated & powerful (& safe of course) heating wearable with their further funding.