# LTC4001 Can charge my 1s4p Li-ion battery pack?

Tags: power-supply, power, batteries, switch-mode-power-supply, charger

I was trying to design a battery charger for my application where I have made a pack of 1s4p cells where each cell is having 2600mAH and Charging rating as 4.2V. So can I consider it as 1 cell?
Can I use **LTC4001 - 2A Synchronous Buck Li-Ion Charger** for this pack?

[LTC4001 Datasheet](http://www.linear.com/product/LTC4001)

Comment: The data states that you can  charge one cell!!!

Comment: It's mentioning as the single cell but my charging potential is 4.2V which is good for my pack and as the batteries are connected in parallel so current to each cell will be approximately 0.5A.

Comment: Does the LTC4001 have any upper capacity limit, for example a fixed timeout of X hours? If not, I see no problem with your approach.

Comment: What if one cell develops a fault? It isn't advisable.

Comment: You might get away with it if the cells are very closely matched.

Comment: @winny Nothing mentioned like upper capacity limit

Comment: @LeonHeller Each cell is of the same type and having the same specification. So it will work?

Comment: They need to be from the same manufacturer, from the same batch.

Comment: This is a nearly duplicate of https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/126673/117785 Batteries in parallel connection must be carefully matched in terms of charge and discharge profile, otherwise the pack is likely to fail and have less than expected capacity. This can be done only at a factory that produces thousands of cells.