# Is it a bad idea to connect two Li-ion batteries in parallel?

Tags: batteries, lithium-ion, circuit-protection, voltage-source

Suppose I have two Li-ion batteries for smartphones. One could say that if they are connected in parallel, then the voltage given to the device would be the same, but the capacity would be doubled, hence doubling the lifetime of the total battery (i.e. more time to use the smartphone without charging it).

However, this seems a bad idea to me. The first thing that crosses my mind is that doing this would lead to huge currents between the two batteries if the voltages are not exactly the same.

Would this approach work? If not, are there any other drawbacks on top of the one I described?

Comment: You must equalize the voltages first! A simple resistor would do.

Comment: @winny And then would it be okay to plug this circuit (battery - resistor - battery) to the device?

Comment: @winny Can you elaborate on your comment? How would one choose a resistor value, how would you know when the voltages were sufficiently equalized, and how much energy would be lost in the resistor?

Comment: There are dozens of questions of this sort on EE.  https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/126673/117785

Comment: One thing I would add about "connecting the circuit to the device" is that the terminals on the device in most or many cases will not connect directly to the battery.  You may have to do quite a lot of research to determine what circuitry already exists and how to alter, take advantage of or connect to it.

Comment: @Eliot Anywhere between 10-100 ohm. Overnight or measure within 10 mV. Plenty of energy lost.

Comment: @Tendero No, remove the resistor once they are equalized.