# Connect 3 Lithium Polymer battery with different capacity in parallel

Tags: batteries, parallel, charging, lipo

I am working on an IoT product with has a total current requirement of 1.3 A at the peak. Due to space constraint, we decided to select Li-Po battery with capacities one with 600 mAh other two with 350 mAh each and the voltage rating is the same 3.7V. to get total 1300 mAh we are connecting them parallel.

Now we are looking for a charging IC which will support this parallel configuration with different capacities and same voltage rating Li-Po batteries. How can we solve it?

Comment: How do you think that ic should handle 3p differently than a single cell?

Comment: I dunno, but with these different capacities, I'd never go near this thingy without a fire extinguisher. This is something battery manufacturers try to avoid at any cost. Is there a special reason for this, or are you just using spare parts?

Comment: You are using different capacity cells in parallel. This is a bad idea as they packs will discharge at different rates, voltages could be different between them and other issues with the health of the cells. Why can't you have four 350mAH cells?

Comment: @Puffafish **If** the batteries are identical (except for their size and capacity) they will balance out and discharge at the same rate (relative to their capacity of  course). I mean, after a full charge (100%), some usage, if the combined battery is at 50% then all individual cells will be at 50%. It is not like the small cell empties first as that would lower it's voltage which cannot happen as the other cells are in parallel with it.

Comment: Unbalanced batteries in parallel is always a bad idea

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Charging Li-ion batteries in parallel](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/126673/charging-li-ion-batteries-in-parallel)

Answer (score 3):

I have seen products where 2 or more different size batteries are used in parallel. For example some [Apple Macbooks](https://www.cnet.com/news/bigger-macbook-pro-battery-equals-higher-replacement-cost/) have this.

**If** the batteries:

- come from the same manufacturer
- use the same chemistry
- are the same "model"
- are balanced (in order to have the same voltage) before connecting in parallel

so **only** differ in size and capacity then I think you can connect different size batteries in parallel. Then you can treat the combination as if it is **one** larger battery.

Then you do not need a special charging circuit, to the charging circuit the battery will behave as one larger battery.

Ideally you would **consult with the battery manufacturer** to confirm that this can be done.

You should **NOT** get some "random" batteries and combine those into one larger battery. That is asking for trouble if you ask me.

Comment: Thank you Bimpelrekkie. But the iPhone XS max is using a different capacity battery to connect parallel and charge it with one Charging IC from TI.

Comment: The iPhone is an Apple product and personally I am not a fan of their design choices. If what you say is true (I'd have to see the schematic to be sure) then probably Apple was unable to meet all the requirements I listed above and/or they use it for some other trick as well. It's Apple so you never know.

Answer (score 1):

You can handle batteries in parallel if they have the same chemistry only different capacities.

The only thing you can really worry is connecting them in parallel while they have different voltage due the different initial state of charge.

Connect them with three resistor like in the following picture and let them settle to the same voltage.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5gc82.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Once you did that connect them firmly in parallel (not with connectors, solder the wires) as caution if somebody thinks to remove and replace only one battery without equalizing the voltages first. Put a warning label to because it's a dangerous thing to do so. You might also glue them permanently together.

Also use a slightly lower rated charger than 1300mA to compensate internal impedance not proportional with the capacity , I understand that you use batteries that only differs on size and capacity, same producer same chemistry so this will not be an issue.

I might also notice that you make a confusion, you can have more than 1300mA peak current with only a 350mAh pack , the maximum peak current is not equal in value with the capacity. The capacity (in mAh) is given by the maximum time on battery (hours) multiplied with the average current (not the peak, in mA). The peak current it's given by the manufacturer and might be up to 40 times capacity (14A for your 350mah battery) , you have to read the manufacturer specifications.

Comment: Thank so much Dorian and sorry for the delayed replay. I could connect them as per the image at first to equalize initial condition. After that whether it is needed to connect the 100-ohm resistor with them or just connect them in parallel without the resistor? 

You said to solder them together, not to connect with a connector, is it because of the different PCB lines make different impedance for each battery so they could cause different characteristics?

Comment: So for selecting the capacity of the battery, I have to only consider the average current required at normal condition, then check with the battery manufacturer to confirm whether it will support the peak current or it will not?

Comment: @sajin It's not about the PCB line but the possibility that someone else later will be tempted to replace only one battery without equalizing the voltage first. The discharge current from a charged battery to a less charged battery can go up to tens of amps which can be extremely dangerous.  For the second question , yes. If you're happy with the capacity vs average consumption I would go with using only the 600mAh battery. Check with the producer, they might have a current limiter circuit inside. Can you specify the battery used?

Comment: Thank you, Dorian. Actually, we didn't fix the battery yet. Looking for a better one. Once we find a better one we will share the datasheet and detailed power requirements with you.